# How to make a Signature of a Global Variable in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

currently im trying to rebuild a function.
I am using makesig.py to create function signatures which I am using for rebuilding. It works fine.

Now im trying to make a signature of a global variable:

[image: that variable]

makesig.py throws me an exception:

[image]

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: You mean you want to label the address. Functions can have signature like return , calling conv , arguments and thier types , storage etc  but a variable has only an address and type for them. Like dword somedword.